# IBM DB2 ODBC Driver Issue [Error 69899] Error occurred in the database host server code. SQLSTATE= S1000

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

After upgrade our IBM System i (aka i5/OS or AS/400) from V5R4 to V7R1, one of our applications that connect to DB2 using ODBC fails with the following error:

```
Error Code: 69899
SQLSTATE: S1000
[IBM] [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5/OS] PWS0005 
Error occurred in the database host server code.
```

The symptoms are:

In a While / Wend loop a CURSOR is declared, then opens, do fetch(s) and close.

If at any iteration the cursor does not retrieve any rows, in the following iteration the error occurs after declaring the cursor (with a different SQL query) when you try to open it.

First we updated the ODBC driver to the latest version available, but the problem persists.

Because we needed an urgent solution, I solved the problem by making a pre-select to determine if the cursor will return rows, otherwise skip that iteration, this solves the problem for now but does not seem a very elegant solution.

Any idea how to get more information about the error that occurs on the host?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, if an error occurs in the server side code, you should call IBM support and report it.  They'll ask if you're on the latest cume and probably the latest database group PTFs.

The server runs the ODBC connexion in a job called QZDASOINIT.  Since there are probably many connexions to the system, there are probably many QZDASOINIT jobs.  To find yours, go to a terminal session and `WRKOBJLCK MYPROFILE *USRPRF`.  You'll be presented with a list of jobs running with your user profile.  At least one of them will be the QZDASOINIT job you're looking for.  Use option 5 to look at the job, then option 10 to see the job log.  Press F10 to see the detailed messages and F18 to go to the bottom (most recent) entries.

If the error was so severe that the server job terminated abnormally, there won't be a lock on your user profile.  Instead, go to the spooled job log by using `WRKSPLF`.

IBM have been logging some SQL internal errors since V5R4.  `select * from qrecovery.qsq901s;` to see any SQLCODE -901 errors.

Comment: Thank for your response.

After have a look in the logs we reported the issue to IBM. Still waiting a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed the latest fix pack for the latest version of System I Access

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error before and it was caused by a syntax error in the connection string.  It was a setting that was insignificant in older versions of the OS and more significant in newer versions, but did not cause the connection itself to fail so it was hard to track down.

For example: Port Number:8471 had a spelling mistake and was Porte Number:8471 hard to spot but once found, it fixed the problem for me. Basically everything past this part of the connection got ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add another solution to this problem.  The SQL Packages that exist on your system get corrupted after/and or during upgrades.  You MUST delete these packages after an upgrade.  This will get rid of the old packages and will allow the system to recreate the packages at the new OS version level.   When deleting SQL packages some connections/jobs may have locks on those packages so you might have to shut host services down.  Use the DLTSQLPKG command to do the delete.  In v7r2 and higher there are some additional steps to do as IBM changed somethings when it comes to packages you can find the info here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1015556

Or tell your ODBC/JDBC/.Net Data adapter/provider to not use packages.  This is probably less desirable as there are performance benefits to packages.